# Problemas en el login de aplicativo

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

Vuelvo a postear esta pregunta de una manera más detallada esperando su ayuda...

1.- Tengo una pantalla index.php que mantiene dos campos como cualquier login en donde se debe ingresar el usuario y la contraseña

```
<form role="form" id="acceso" name="acceso" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <label class="block clearfix">
      <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="" />
      <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </span>
      </label>
      <label class="block clearfix">
      <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="" />
      <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
      </span>
      </label>
      <div class="space"></div>
      <div class="clearfix">
         <button id="btn-ingresar" name="btn-ingresar" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Ingresar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="space-4"></div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

2.- Para validar los campos utilizo jquery.validate en donde la validación a más de las reglas en los campo usuario y contraseña envía la información a un archivo .php en la capa de la base de datos en donde nos interesa el resultado con el numeral 9 que corresponde a que puede ingresar al aplicativo por cumplir con todas las reglas de validacion

```
$(function() {
        var timeSlide = 1000;
        $("#acceso").validate({
                rules: {
                    "email": {
                        "required": true,
                        "email": true,
                    },
                    "password": {
                        "required": true,
                        "minlength": "5"
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    "email": {
                        "required": "Ingrese su email",
                        "email": "Email invalido",
                    },
                    "password": {
                        "required": "Ingrese su contraseña",
                        "minlength": "Mínimo 5 caracteres"
                    },
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $('.alert-success, .alert-danger, .alert-info, .alert-warning').slideUp(timeSlide);
                    var dataString = 'email=' + $('#email').val() + '&password=' + $('#password').val() + '&formid=1';
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "includes/conectar.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            success: function(msj) {
                                // Validaciones de acceso
                                if (msj == 9) {
                                    $(form).find('#btn-ingresar').attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("value", "Ingresando...");
                                    $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="alert alert-success"></div>');
                                    $('.alert-success').hide(0).html('Acceso correcto, ingresando al sistema...');
                                    $('.alert-success').slideDown(timeSlide);
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        window.location.href = "home.php?c=index";
                                    }, (timeSlide + 1000));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
$('#email').val('');
$('#password').val('');
}
})
}
})
})
```

3.- Aquí es cuando tenemos el inconveniente que se presenta, ya que el código debe redireccionar a home.php?c=index como podemos ver en el código enviado

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "home.php?c=index"; },(timeSlide + 1000));
```

pero al llegar a esta parte, el sistema redirecciona a index.php para nuevamente indicar al usuario que debe ingresar el usuario y contraseña.  Obviamente el usuario lo vuelve a ingresar y al llegar a esta instrucción el sistema da el acceso sin problema alguno a los usuarios.

LA pregunta corresponde a por que sucede este evento y debemos ingresar dos veces el usuario y contraseña ya que las pruebas realizadas en localhost (desarrollo) no da ningún error, pero si sucede esto en producción....

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que los usuarios se encuentran molestos por realizar este proceso dos veces cada vez que se loguean al aplicativo.

Saludos

Comment: como tienes tu archivo .php que mencionas en el punto 2

Comment: el archivo .php lo que hace es conectarse a la bdd y luego de las validaciones de usuario existente y clave correcta devuelve el número 9 como exitoso y lo único que se hace es validar el resultado para que ingrese en el if del archivo .js que publico para que llegue a la instrucción de redirección a home.php?c=index

Comment: Te comento que me paso algo similar y el problema fue que en al inicializar la session de php tenian asi: session_start('usuario');

Comment: al reemplazar ello por : session_start(); es decir sin la variable funciono todo bn !!

Comment: Muchaslas gracias por tu aporte primeramente... ahora te cuento que cambie las instrucciones como me indicas, pues en el archivo .php en donde inicio la session y obviamente defino las variables dentro de la misma, pero sigue con el mismo comportamiento... es decir debo ingresar dos veces el usuario y clave y funciona correctamente el aplicativo... pero sigo con el mismo problema...

Comment: podrias incluir el codigo de tu archivo php ..

Comment: Esto tambien puede ocurrir cuando las cookies de de sesion no son creadas de forma global al dominio, y se hacen saltos entre subdominios. Por ejemplo la misma url con y sin `www.`, revisa esto, es probable que el error venga por ahí, por la explicacion qui das del problema.

Comment: aquí el código del archivo .php que valida el acceso y donde se crea la session para su revisión ya que no encuentro la manera de manejar las cookies entre dominios

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
           session_start([
            'cookie_lifetime' => 0, 
            'read_and_close'  => true,
           ]); 
           session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], 0);
           //
           if (isset($_SESSION['mark']) === false){
            session_regenerate_id(true);
            $_SESSION['mark'] = true;
           }
           //